# (RSpec) How do I check if an object is created?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I want to test if expected exception handling is taking place in the following Ruby code through RSpec. Through testing I realized that I cannot use the `raise_error` matcher to test if the exception was raised, after rescuing it.

So, now I want to test whether objects of `CustomError` and `StandardError` are created to see if the error was raised as expected.

*test.rb*

```
module TestModule
  class Test
    class CustomError < StandardError
    end

    def self.func(arg1, arg2)
      raise CustomError, 'Inside CustomError' if arg1 >= 10 && arg2 <= -10
      raise StandardError, 'Inside StandardError' if arg1.zero? && arg2.zero?
    rescue CustomError => e
      puts 'Rescuing CustomError'
      puts e.exception
    rescue StandardError => e
      puts 'Rescuing StandardError'
      puts e.exception
    ensure
      puts "arg1: #{arg1}, arg2: #{arg2}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

*test_spec.rb*

```
require './test'

module TestModule
  describe Test do
    describe '#func' do
      it 'raises CustomError when arg1 >= 10 and arg2 <= -10' do
        described_class.func(11, -11)
        expect(described_class::CustomError).to receive(:new)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the above code I get the following error

```
 Failures:

  1) TestModule::Test#func raises CustomError when arg1 >= 10 and arg2 <= -10
     Failure/Error: expect(described_class::CustomError).to receive(:new)
     
       (TestModule::Test::CustomError (class)).new(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./test_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <module:TestModule>'
```

The idea was that if `CustomError` is being raised, it's obejct must be created using `new` and I can test that using RSpec. However, as you can see, this isn't working.

What am I missing?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Why don't you test that the output (`puts`) is as expected? To me, it feels like the Exception is an implementation detail and I would focus on the expected output.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Move the expectation `expect(described_class::CustomError).to receive(:new)` before calling the unit under test `described_class.func(11, -11)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to test implementation details (what happens inside the method), and usually it's a bad idea. If a particular path leads to an exception but you want this exception to be swallowed - test that.

consider

```rb
def weird_division(x, y)
  x/y 
rescue ZeroDivisionError => e
  return "Boom!"
end
```

No need to test that `ZeroDivisionError` has been created, that's an implementation detail (akin to testing private methods). Test behavior that is "visible" from the outside.

```rb
expect(weird_division(1/0)).to return "Boom!"
```

Because you might change the implementation:

```rb
def weird_division(x, y)
  return "Boom!" if y == 0
  x/y 
end
```

And your tests would start failing, even though the method behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities.

1. If you want to continue with your assertion you can use `have_received` instead of `receive`. This will allow you to keep you assertion after you act.

   `expect(described_class::CustomError).to have_received(:new)`
2. As mentioned in comments test your puts. Which is ultimately the way that you check if your method does what you want.

```
    it 'puts the output' do
        expect do
           described_class.func(11, -11)
        end.to output('Some string you want to print').to_stdout
    end
```